# Install4j build fails with "GC overhead limit exceeded" error

Tags: java, out-of-memory, install4j

I am using install4j (v6.1.5) to create an installer. I have enabled pack200 compression. While creating an installer on my local machine, the installer fails with the following error message:

```
Build failed.

Cause: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
       GC overhead limit exceeded
Stack trace:

com.a.a.d: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.install4j.b.k.c(ejt:158)
    at com.install4j.gui.a.run(ejt:99)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"
```

Where can I change the settings so as to increase the memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the -Xmx value in the file

```
bin/install4j.vmoptions
```

Answer (score 2):

The GC needs to run too frequently. You can try to disable this check with `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit` command line option, and see what happens - usually not a good idea, but I presume that Install4J code is not bugged or leaking. Or you can experiment with bigger heap size with the `-Xmx` option.